# How can user discoverability permission revoked in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am curious wether user can somehow change discoverability permission. I haven't found a way in Settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it on your device in `Settings` / `iCloud` / `iCloud Drive` / `Find via Email`

Comment: I really do hope that Apple will move that setting to privacy.

Comment: Probably it will be easier allow user change that settings right in your app.

Comment: This list is empty in iOS 8.3! Where did it go??

Comment: Also empty in iOS 8.4.

Comment: Do you have some app in your device wich use cloudKit?

Comment: This is strange. In iOS 8.4 the Find by email option shows an empty screen. The list below of apps in the iCloud Drive are (after testing) whether you permit access to cloudkit for the app in general. Not specifically discoverability